# Intercept TAB Key in WebView2

Tags: c++, com, microsoft-edge, webview2

I want to intercept the Tab key inside Webview2.

It is possible to intercept a lot of function keys via `ICoreWebView2AcceleratorKeyPressedEventHandler` that I register with `add_AcceleratorKeyPressed`

But some keys like the cursor keys and the TAB key doesn't call this event handler. Same for the F5 key, it seams that some keys are reserved, strange because the position keys up, down, pos1, end can be intercepted.

Because the window of the WebView2 itself is located in another process there is no chance for me to use standard subclassing and I want to avoid to do subclassing with a hook.

Comment: You write a javascript `keydown` eventhandler, then you can use `window.chrome.webview.postMessage` to send a message to the `WebView2` control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have you any link or source that shows this basic use for a Win32/COM application?

Comment: This page: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32 shows how to inject a script and receive a message.

Comment: It doesn't work with TAB key because TAB is not considered as [Accelerator Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-keyboard-accelerators#accelerator-keystroke-assignments). I agree with Poul's opinion. You can find how to communicate between host and web content using `postMessage` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32#step-6---communication-between-host-and-web-content).

Comment: Tab can be used as an accelerator as any other character keystroke on the keyboard. Depending on WM_GETDLGCODE I can accept Tab in an edit control or use it in dialog navigation. I have full control here. Why shouldn't it be one? It just seams that some characters are not used to call this callback. 
In fact I have currently not enough knowledge to create such a script. I will try this way.

Comment: I find a more detailed example of WebView2 C++ and there's a paragraph about [Communicating the WebViews](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Browser#some-interesting-features). It has example to show how to use `window.chrome.webview.postMessage` and add an event listener for received messages on JavaScript side. You can also refer to it.

Comment: Cursor keys **do trigger** this event! TAB does not trigger it. Per documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2controller?view=webview2-1.0.2045.28#add_acceleratorkeypressed - A key is considered an accelerator if either: 1. Ctrl or Alt is currently being held, or 2. the pressed key does not map to a character. A few specific keys are never considered accelerators, such as Shift. The Escape key is always considered an accelerator. So you can intercept CTRL+A but not "A" alone because that maps to a char and CTRL+A does not.

Comment: Also F5 triggers event as well. But it is also the "reload" key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the discussion I solved the problem.

First I injected a Java script into the browser

```
m_spWebView->AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreated(
    L"window.document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {\n"
    L" if (e.keyCode===9 || e.keyCode===13) {\n"
    L"  window.chrome.webview.postMessage('" CHAR_TOKEN L"'+e.keyCode.toString()); \n"
    L"  e.preventDefault(); \n"
    L"}});\n"
    ,Callback<ICoreWebView2AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedCompletedHandler>(this,&CBrowserWV2Wnd::OnAddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreated).Get()
);
```

Than I added an `ICoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventHandler` with `add_WebMessageReceived` to handle the appropriate message from the hosted WebView2.

```
LPWSTR pwStr = nullptr;
args->TryGetWebMessageAsString(&pwStr);
if (_wcsnicmp(pwStr,CHAR_TOKEN,MfxCountOf(CHAR_TOKEN)-1)==0)
{
    // Get the Keycode from the message
    auto iChar = wcstol(pwStr+MfxCountOf(CHAR_TOKEN)-1,nullptr,10);
    // Do something with the intercepted character
    ...
}
::CoTaskMemFree(pwStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: That will only work if `CoreWebView2Settings.IsScriptEnabled` Property is enabled. When disabled, it disables JavaScript and any `onkeydown` JavaScript event.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to intercept keystrokes is as follows:
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1215

By setting `AdditionalBrowserArguments("--enable-features=msWebView2BrowserHitTransparent")` on `CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions`, the host window can receive messages
by PreTranslateMessage for further processing.

Comment: I tried this, but the host window didn't receive tab in AcceleratorKeyPressed handler.

Comment: I can get the message from the host window by PreTranslateMessage.